How do I implement a gradle linter in a project, with the exported xml from Intellij?
I'm trying to find a linter for gradle that takes in the xml exported from the intellij and checks if it follows as per the config provided.
The config looks like
<code_scheme name="Default" version="173">
  <JavaCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="CLASS_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="9999" />
    <option name="NAMES_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="9999" />
    <option name="JD_ALIGN_PARAM_COMMENTS" value="false" />
    <option name="JD_ALIGN_EXCEPTION_COMMENTS" value="false" />
  </JavaCodeStyleSettings>
  <JetCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="CODE_STYLE_DEFAULTS" value="KOTLIN_OFFICIAL" />
  </JetCodeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="kotlin">
    <option name="CODE_STYLE_DEFAULTS" value="KOTLIN_OFFICIAL" />
  </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>

I did found some that would do for its custom xml, I'm trying to find something that could be imported easily and shared with colleagues.
I tried few of the gradle linter plugings

checkstyle
spotless

The linters have their own xml format and doesn't support the xml provided by intellij.
